# How to add a location block that applies to all incoming requests?

Tags: nginx, http

I would like any incoming HTTP request (regardless of domain name) that begin with a certain path to be sent to a local server. For example:

```
location /special/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
}
```

If there is no matching `server {}` block for a given domain name, Nginx will route the request to the `default_server`. But I need the request to **always** be routed to the local server, *even if a matching `server {}` block is found*.

How would I go about this?

Bonus: if there is a way to do this outside of the `server {}` that currently has `default_server` set, that would be awesome.

Comment: Your question isn't as clear as it could be. Do you mean that any request to hit the server on a given path, regardless of domain name, should be proxied to another service?

Comment: @Tim yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might have to configure a suitable block in every server. You can do this with an include rather than copy and paste. This should work in the default server.

So in each server block use something like this

```
 include /etc/nginx/fragments/path.conf
```

And in /etc/nginx/fragments/path.conf

```
location /special/path/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
}
```

Note that you shouldn't put it in the sites-enabled directory as the nginx.conf includes them, and it's invalid syntax in that context.

Someone else may have a better way than this, but I believe this will work.

Comment: I believe this is the only way (you beat me to it :)). `nginx` will map every request to a server block and doesn't know such a thing as a "default location block".